# SwiftUI Navigation Bar doesn't disappear

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios-navigationview

I have a `NavigationView` where I set the `.navigationBarHidden(true)` in my `SplashScreen`. Here it correctly does not display, however when I go to the next screen the `NavigationView` bar appears. How can i properly hide the navigation bar? The background does also not properly display.

View

```
struct EventsScreen: View {

    var eventsRepository: EventsRepository

    @State
    var currentPage: Int = 0
    @State
    private var searchTerm : String = ""


    func getEventSections() -> [EventSection] {
        eventsRepository.fetchEventSections()
    }

    func getViewControllers() -> [UIHostingController<EventFeatureView>] {
        return eventsRepository.fetchFeaturedEvents().map({ event in
            UIHostingController(rootView: EventFeatureView(event: event))
        })
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {

                    EventViewController(controllers: self.getViewControllers(), currentPage: self.$currentPage)
                    VStack {
                        SearchBar(text: $searchTerm)
                            .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: 16, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 16))
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Chip(text: "Dates", action:  {
                                //TODO filter on dates
                            })
                            Chip(text:"Type", action: {
                                //TODO filter event type
                            })
                            Chip(text: "Points", action: {
                                //TODO filter points
                            })
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                    .frame(height: 600)
                ForEach(self.getEventSections()) { section in
                    EventSectionView(eventSection: section)
                }
            }
        }
        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.black, ColorTheme.brandPurple.color]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Events"), displayMode: .inline)
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `.navigationBarHidden(true)` for the child `View` being presented within the `NavigationView`. I'm not sure what the next screen `View` looks like, but here's something I would try:

```
struct NextScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            // existing body content
        }
        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.black, ColorTheme.brandPurple.color]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Next Screen"), displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

The `Group` is just in case your body content isn't all wrapped in a `View` (e.g. `VStack`, `List`, etc.) of some kind.

It might help to think about it like this:

`NavigationView` will typically inherit `.navigationBarHidden()` from its child views. However, since `.navigationBarHidden()` and `.background()` are explicitly defined outside of the `NavigationView` in `EventsScreen`, they happen to work their ways down and apply to the child views in `EventsScreen` as well (unless those views have their own explicitly defined properties).

While the `NextScreen` View is still presented within the `NavigationView`, the `NextScreen` is initialized with its own default properties, like background color. Once the app navigates/updates to `NextScreen`, the properties of `NextScreen` will take precedent, including the default of `.navigationBarHidden(false)`, and likely the system background color. It's about which View (and its properties) will take precedent, and SwiftUI tends to give first dibs to the children, and broadening from there (provided that the scope of a given property applies to its parent views).

So in summary, those defaults must be explicitly overridden in every View that appears within the `NavigationView`, if you want them to remain changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what SDK says:

> ```
> /// Hides the navigation bar for this view.
> ///
> /// This modifier only takes effect when this view is inside of and visible
> /// within a `NavigationView`.
> ///
> /// - Parameters:
> ///     - hidden: A Boolean value that indicates whether to hide the
> ///       navigation bar.
> @available(OSX, unavailable)
> public func navigationBarHidden(_ hidden: Bool) -> some View
> ```

so, you have to set it to `false` for *every* top view showing in `NavigationView` during navigation, otherwise it will be shown as you observe.

Comment: How can I then make this a top view?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your code like this:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ...
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Events"), displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
    // that means only show one view at a time no matter what device I'm working
    .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
}
```

You can bind `navigationBarHidden` to variable, so that you can change the value under certain conditions. Like this: .navigationBarHidden($onOff)